# title bar like wunderlist tideSDK

Tags: titlebar, tidesdk, wunderlist

Firstly sorry for my English because I don't speak very well!

Can you tell me how can I create title bar like Wunderlist in tideSDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to wunder. The sources for Wunderlist are open source under the Apache 2 license and available at:

https://github.com/6wunderkinder/wunderlist.

You can view the user interface for yourself to examine how the app was constructed.